# How to enable Puppet's debug logging level from Beaker

Tags: ruby, logging, rspec, puppet, beaker

I have some `beaker-rspec` acceptance tests covering a Puppet module I am creating, and would like to know how to enable debug logging on the underlying Puppet calls (e.g., know exactly what happens when I call `apply_manifest`).  I'm pretty sure I've been been able to get debug logging working on Beaker itself (`export BEAKER_debug=yes`?), but that only seems to tell me what *Beaker* is doing, not necessarily Puppet.

If it helps, here are some relevant file snippets:

`spec/fixtures/spec_helper_acceptance.rb`

```
require 'beaker-rspec/spec_helper'
require 'beaker-rspec/helpers/serverspec'
require 'beaker/librarian'

RSpec.configure do |c|
  module_root = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..'))

  c.formatter = :documentation

  # Configure all nodes in nodeset
  c.before :suite do
    install_puppet
    install_librarian
    librarian_install_modules(module_root, 'mymodule')
  end
end
```

`spec/acceptance/example_spec.rb`

```
require 'spec_helper_acceptance'

apply_manifest_opts = {
  :catch_failures => true,
  # I seem to need this otherwise Puppet doesn't pick up the required modules.
  # Is this where I can also enable debug logging in Puppet? 
  :modulepath     => '/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/',
}

default_pp = <<-EOS
  class { 'mymodule': }
EOS

describe 'the mymodule class' do
  describe 'given default params' do
    it 'should return successfully' do
      expect(apply_manifest(default_pp, apply_manifest_opts).exit_code).to be_zero
    end
  end
end
```

I'm actually trying to work out why the `the mymodule class given default params should return successfully` test fails, but at the moment I only get

```
Failure/Error: expect(apply_manifest(default_pp, apply_manifest_opts).exit_code).to be_zero
       expected `2.zero?` to return true, got false
```

which is not much help.  Do you see my problem?

I'll accept responses that either answer my question directly, or give me some other way to work out *why* the exit code is non-zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was right on my hunch that it just needed an extra option supplied to `apply_manifest`.  It just took me a while to work out exactly where the documentation was on how to do it.

```
apply_manifest_opts = {
  :catch_failures => true,
  # I seem to need this otherwise Puppet doesn't pick up the required modules. 
  :modulepath     => '/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/',
  :debug          => true,
}
```

Source:

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/puppetlabs/beaker/Beaker/DSL/Helpers/PuppetHelpers#apply_manifest_on-instance_method